# Round 0.5 to up(1)

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables

can you explain why the number for example `0.3095` is rounded to `0.309` and not to `0.310`.

If  number is`0.3094` rounded is `0.309` that is OK

If  number is`0.3096` rounded is `0.310` that is OK

The problem is when rounding 5.

I'm using calculations in datatables like:

```
...
      { "data": "columndata"  ,
      render: function(data, type, row){
          return parseFloat(data/1000).toFixed(3);
      } },
...
```

Where `columndata` is `309.500` before calculation.

Here is test case:

https://jsfiddle.net/to8p2hdy/

Test case of working solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/to8p2hdy/1/

Why `Math.round` do the trick but only `parsefloat` did not?

Comment: Are you sure it is `309.500` and not i.e. `309.4999999999` which is just displayed as `309.500`?

Comment: Yes in the DB is exactly 309.5

Comment: @HristianYordanov: what data type is that column? But this rounding seems to be done in PHP, not in the database.

Comment: @SebDieBln I add test case in jsfiddle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added working solution to the topic

Comment: So this is completely independent of PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

You stumbled upon the fact that some decimal numbers do not have an exact representation in the binary system. For example `0.1` can not be represented in the binary system, the closest we get is `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

This is much like "a third" can not be represented in the decimal system because it would need to be `0.333333...`.

Go to https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ and find that `0.3095` can not be repesented by a float but instead becomes `0.30949999999999999733546474089962430298328399658203125`, which is rounded down instead of up.

Comment: Oh I see. Ok but `Math.round` is rounding `0.3095` to `0.31`.

Comment: @HristianYordanov Hm, `Math.round` outputs an integer, not `0.31`. How exactly do you call it?

Comment: I use it in to the test solution at the end of the question.

Comment: @HristianYordanov In the test solution you call `Math.round(309.5)` and get `310`. That is expected. You then divide by `1000` to get `0.310` which again is not representable in the binary system but rather is something like `0.309999....`. You are just lucky that it is rounded by `toFixed(3)` the same way the original number would have been.